# Computer case front bay fan?

Tags: cooling, fan

I've recently built a new sandy bridge rig for my computer.

Up until now, I've mostly been running low - mid performance PC's with no need for extra case fans and such.

However with this new rig (i5 2500k, radeon 6850), I've noticed my computer temperatures reaching new highs. I've installed a 120mm side intake fan (points directly at cpu) as well as an intake fan on the back. I've been reading up on airflow and such and since I only have 1 front bay drive I was thinking of making use of the space and placing 2 60MM fans there for exhaust.

Is this a good idea? and Would that help increase the airflow through my case?

any criticisms/suggestions are welcome ! :D

Comment: Rear fans are usually meant to be outtake fans, so be sure you are supposed to have intake fan there. It could be causing problems with airflow.

Comment: That fan – which as you said is above the CPU – I would have thought it might be better for it to be exhausting air. My reason for thinking about this is the fact that the CPU fan would be blowing air away from it so a fan pushing air towards it has the possibility to create a hotspot. Someone correct me if I am wrong. I don't in any way claim to be an expert (not even close) – just making my observations. Although you can get exhaust fans which go in the same location at the back of the case as items like the GPU, and any PCI cards, one of those could be useful for pulling the hot air away fr

Comment: your ridiculous fan setup aside, or in addition to your ridiculous fan setup, it could also be the CPU just runs hotter than the previous one you had.

Answer (score 4):

My rule of thumb is to always intake from low points in the case and exhaust from high points in the case. Heat rises.

That said, do you have vents for these exhausts? If so, go for it. If not, simply putting more fans inside your case without vents won't help you much.

Answer (score 4):

Most cases are designed to flow air **IN the front/side and OUT the back**.  Putting an intake on the back where the PSU exhausts its hot air (and there's usually a house wall restricting airflow away from the box) pulls that hot air back inside.